# list to NSIndexPath monotouch

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic, xamarin.ios

I am trying to add records dynamically to an already populated UITable. In my UITableView class I have a custom List object

```
List<CustomObject> _data=new List<CustomObject>();
```

where I add records to from my webservice call like so:

```
 _data.Add(Json(Object));// Json returns a list of CustomObject

 //table is a UITableView
 //this.table.InsertRows(_data);
```

I know this above line won't work because its expecting an NSIndexPath[] but I am not sure how to go about adding the new items an load only the new items added. I don't really follow objective C very well so  examples I found don't help so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you will add data to your List, and then call ReloadData() on your TableView.  You usually only call InsertRows() if you want to insert data at a particular spot in the table based on some sort of user action.

Comment: but wouldn't that reload the whole table, shouldn't that bring in performance issues if you're paging from your webservice?

Comment: The TableView will only redraw the rows that are currently in view.

Comment: Thanks this is the way I was thinking but wasn't sure if their was a better route, your comment gave me a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a List of `CusomObject` as `CusomObject` to a `List<CusomObject>` ,that is not quite right.you should be adding a `CusomObject` to `List<CusomObject>`.